# PHP and Mysql, about delete record if field has 2 occurrences of $, dollar sign in price field

Tags: php, mysql, count, duplicates, records

thanks for reading first of all.

The price field  sometimes are in invalid form.  the default form of the value should be $xxx.xx   however ,sometimes it may show   $xxx.xx$xxx.xx  which is something I want to remove completely.  I basically just want to delete the row if error happens in the price field.

I was able to do a check with a php function to simply check for that, but it seems to take a long time to do so since it has to loop through every records(about 2000+). Is there a better and faster way to do this? perhaps directly in MYSQL commands?

The intent is to verify the price field to make sure it does not have duplicate dollar signs and if so delete them before further processing is done.

```
        if(substr_count($deleterow['product_price'], "$") >= 2 || $deleterow['product_StoreItemNumber'] = null)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE table SET produce_price=0 WHERE produce_price LIKE '%$$%'
```

Just let the database do the work.

Edited to allow pricing as previously shown (btw really bad to store the price symbol in a column, the column should be decimal(10,2) format and just store the price value ie xxx.xx in it your currency symbol should be in application.

```
UPDATE table SET produce_price='$0.00' WHERE produce_price LIKE '%$%$%' OR produce_price LIKE '%$$%'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to make sure a price sign doesn't have duplicate dollar signs, first you have to ask why your price column allows dollar signs. It should really be a numeric.

That said, the way to find the number of occurrences of a character within a string in MySQL is to take the length of the string, then subtract from it the length of the string with the character removed. For example:

1. `price` = '$123.45$'` (length=8)
2. `REPLACE(price, '$', '') =`123.45` (length=8)
3. `8 - 6 = 2`, so there are two `$` in `price.

So in MySQL the logic would be something like thisL:

```
WHERE LENGTH(price) - LENGTH(REPLACE(price, '$', '')) >= 2
```

Or, you could update all `price` values to have just one dollar sign by removing all dollar signs and then prepending a dollar sign to the value. This will update all rows but they'll all have the single dollar sign:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET price = CONCAT('$', REPLACE(price, '$', ''))
```

But again, you should really be using a numeric column and formatting the price in your front end code.